# How to tell the linking type of an elf file?

Tags: linux, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I'm doing a script that checking the elf file, and in some point it need to check the linking type for it.
So,
Is there any tools in Linux or stable way that I can use to check if an output file is totally static linked or dynamic linked?

'ld.so --verify' can check if the file is dynamic linked, but it also check if is it handable by this linker, so I can not use the result as the determing for link type.

Other tools like 'nm','file' do check the output file and provide some information about linking type by print message, which make it not very reliable to use..e.g. if I write script to grep words 'dynamically linked' 'statically linked' of standard output from 'file $filename' as a verify of the link type doesn't feel reliable..

so, Is there any simple way or small tools to check the link type? or why it is not possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ldd` on a binary if it's dynamically linked it prints the shared libraries and returns `0`, if it was statically linked it returns `1`

Comment: thanks. but i have checked the source code for ldd, don't think ldd return 1 only when it is not dynamic linked, it could be other reason also, so I can't use that result.

Comment: @user1836141 true, if the file doesn't exist or not an elf, you could check before using ldd, also note that any other command will have the same problems.

Comment: there is a command called 'readelf -d' which check the dynamic section of the elf file, but unfortunatlly it return 0 even there is no dynamic section in it.... otherwise it could be the solution. Another possible solution is use 'readelf -h' to list the elf header section and then grep the output... which again...not beautiful at all but maybe more reliable than others... I don't know... hope I can get some better solutions.

Comment: @user1836141 even if it did, it would still fail if the file is not there or if it's not an elf, the point is, you should do those checks before calling `ldd` or whatever, that's the most robust way to do it.

Comment: It could be done. but then I really need to make sure how many error cases will be returned in ldd and if there is more error than file name failed or so, then doing all the check by myself feels like redo half of the ldd code :) but yeah. it could be done. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a utility that does specifically what you are looking for - as mentioned, `ldd` can be (ab-)used to determine it. `file` might also be of use. But the information is in the ELF header and just needs to be parsed correctly, so writing a simple program to do it shouldn't be difficult...

Comment: how can I use ldd to do it? I guess if there is no existing tool for this, then i need to parse the elf header.

Comment: I guess it may depend on your version of `ldd` - the one I have reports `not a dynamic executable` for static-linked binaries and exits with a `1` exit code, where with dynamic binaries, it lists the dependencies and exits with `0`...

Comment: yeah, but as Mux has answered upstairs, i think ldd return error 1 not only when it is not dynamica linked, could be other error too. so....

Comment: Right, so unless you check things first (file exists, is a file and not a symlink, directory, etc, you have read permission on it, etc...) you might get false errors. `file` might be more useful than `ldd` in that respect, as you'll get a more appropriate textual indication of the file type.